# Can I start my 9 month study program 5 days before my 3 month student visa expires?

Tags: visas, switzerland

I received a student visa from Switzerland on 17th October 2017, which is valid for three months. I plan to start January 11th 2018. The visa is valid until January 16th 2018. Will I encounter any problems due to my starting dates. My MBA program is for the duration of 9 months.

The visa I was given is 3 months which is standard Visitors Visa. I hope I won't encounter problems.

What other documents will the immigration officers ask for to prove I'm for study.

Comment: Please give your question an appropriate title.

Comment: why didn't you get a visa for the duration of your studies?

Comment: Did you actually ask for (and get) a student visa (D), or a standard visitor's visa (C)? It looks like you have a standard 3-month visitors visa, which definitely doesn't allow you to stay for a 9-month program. You will need to ask for a student visa covering that period. In other circumstances you could have entered Switzerland on the 3-month visitor's visa and then asked for a residency permit, but I doubt this would be applicable in these circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

> The visa I was given is 3 months which is standard Visitors Visa. I hope I won't encounter problems.

That means your long term study on that visitor visa will be illegal, plain and simple.

Apply for the proper visa which covers the period of your study or which is extendable to that effect. A tourist visa does not allow long term study.